# How do I get all the rows in one table that are not in another in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have tried a bunch of different things but always get syntax errors.

I have two tables - tableA and tableB. They both have a con_number field as a unique ID.
I want to select all of the rows in tableB that do not exist in tableA.

Can anyone please give me this query as it would be in MS Access?

I know that using NOT IN is quite inefficient in this case so if there is a better way then that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT TableB.con_number
FROM TableB
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM TableA 
                  WHERE TableA.con_number = TableB.con_number);
```

Comment: Beat me too ;-) You can increase the readability of your post by indenting each line by 4 spaces (highlighting it and pressing the code sample button does this for you)

Comment: @Ian Quigley: the posted SQL doesn't use NOT IN, rather it uses NOT EXISTS.

Comment: +1 I looked into it, and Not exists is just as quick. Deleted my answer. My Bad!

Comment: Why the value of 1 from the "SELECT 1" line?

Answer (score 2):

NOT IN version (slow but sure):

```
SELECT con_number
FROM TableB
WHERE con_number NOT IN (SELECT con_number FROM tableA);
```

experimental version (don't know if this is any faster, just try it out):

```
SELECT B.con_number, MAX(A.con_number) AS check
FROM tableB B LEFT JOIN tableA A ON B.con_number = A.con_number
GROUP BY B.con_number
HAVING check IS NULL;
```

Note: Both should be fairly standard SQL, I don't know any ms-access specific features

Answer (score 2):

There is a Find Unmatched wizard that will set this up. The SQL is:

```
SELECT TableB.con_number
FROM TableB LEFT JOIN TableA 
ON TableB.con_number = TableA.con_number
WHERE TableA.con_number Is Null
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember something like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA.* LEFT JOIN TableB _
    ON TableA.con_number = TableB.con_number WHERE 'criteria'
```

But I don't remember which 'criteria' to use

```
... TableA.con_number <> TableB.con_Number
... TableB.con_number IS NULL
... TableA.con_number NOT like TableB.con_Number
```