# MS Access SQL: Return rows from Table 1 that aren't in Table 2

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm comparing two datasets using MS Access SQL, which appears to be a common problem on StackOverflow.

I found a similar question with what I think is a working answer, but there's a piece of the answer that I don't understand.

The link:
[How do I get all the rows in one table that are not in another in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724341/how-do-i-get-all-the-rows-in-one-table-that-are-not-in-another-in-ms-access/724357#comment43033317_724357][1])

The accepted and most upvoted answer:

```
SELECT TableB.con_number
FROM TableB
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM TableA 
                  WHERE TableA.con_number = TableB.con_number);
```

I don't understand the `1` in the `SELECT 1` statement. Why is there a `1`?

Comment: There is an MS Access query wizard to find unmatched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `1` could be anything. You could put "Fart" there if you wish. That subquery must return something though in order for the "NOT EXISTS" to see if there is something when `TableA.con_number = TableB.con_number`

That being said, it seems like a better query might be:

```
SELECT TableB.con_number
FROM tableB
    LEFT JOIN TableA on
        TableB.con_number=TableA.con_number
WHERE tableA.Con_Number IS NULL
GROUP BY TableB.Con_number
```

Unless there is some nuance to these tables that I'm missing.

Comment: I'm only armed with enough information to be dangerous, but the information I've seen suggests that `LEFT JOIN` is inefficient.  Is `LEFT JOIN` only inefficient when certain table conditions are present?

Comment: It's true that a LEFT JOIN is generally less efficient than an INNER JOIN, but I can guarantee any workaround you do to perform the same function that the LEFT JOIN performs will be less efficient than the LEFT JOIN itself. Furthermore, in this case the workaround is to use a Derived Table (subquery), which is generally less efficient than a LEFT JOIN. Also, this is Access and we aren't talking about hundreds of millions of records, so either way you are probably fine.

Comment: MS Access...for now. ;)